# Increasing Midninght commander dark white contrast

Tags: windows-10, debian, putty, colors, midnight-commander

Midnight commander is used from putty client from Windows 10 in Debian 10.

Its file names are low contract (dark white) and are difficult to read notebook screen in heavy sunlight:

[image]

Directory names are OK but file names are difficult to read.

I tried all color schemas from Midnight Commander menu but all of them have same issue. file names are  in low contast dark white.
How to make files names more contrast like in Far ?

Comment: You could try `mc -b` to disable colors altogether. If no color scheme gives you a good result, then the problem is with your font . Either too small or too thin.

Comment: putty shows mc fonts very thin. How to make fonts to apper better in putty, like in far window ?

Comment: Your link returns `not found`